# Who is this green guy?

Tags: fairy-tail

While watching episode 114 (Erza vs Azuma) I noticed a little green (pig samurai?) guy in the background.  Any idea who or what this is?

(click for full size)
[image]

Comment: Azuma maybe perhaps?

Comment: It doesn't look like [Azuma](http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111115162928/fairytail/images/f/f0/Azuma_full_body.JPG)

Comment: [But](http://i.imgur.com/8v8Y96e.jpg) [wait](http://i.imgur.com/e8nsdht.png), [there's](http://i.imgur.com/iomz4Lv.png) [more](http://i.imgur.com/txbJH.jpg). They seem to be a Rave Master reference.

Comment: http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Rave_Master

Comment: That little green guy is in lots of other episodes too. I had questions about him as well, but seeing he serves no purpose is actually quite funny now that I think about it. He's also in episode 134. Which is the current episode I'm on 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The person (Well technically not people) you spotted are called "easter eggs".

> Src from here: [fairytail.answers.wikia.com](http://fairytail.answers.wikia.com/wiki/What_is_that_hidden_green_character_i%27m_starting_to_see_in_the_background_in_some_of_the_episodes)

---

> In every episode, at least once, a little creature is placed somewhere.... **These creatures are known as "easter eggs", as they appear in the anime but serve no purpose. They are not part of the plot, nor an important factor in the anime.....**

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7wX-DY2XIo) is a YouTube video of all the easter eggs that appear in fairy tail. If you want to see the scene that you referred to, just skip to 3:26.

[image: Anyway here's the image you referred to]

Different types that appear (Sometimes multiple times are)

- Green one's with a white square with arms and legs
- An Exceed
- A little pink mouse

And some others too like these:

[image]
[image]

Oh yeah, and look, I found the green "easter egg" from the photo you provided too. ^^

Comment: I'm amazed I managed to go over 100 episodes without noticing any before.  Thanks for the video.  At 5 seconds in looks to be bigger image of the same character as from the original screenshot.

Answer (score -3):

one of the members of the spriggan 12 has a thing sitting on their sholder that is about the same size but i don't know if it would be him.[image]