# Is there an explanation behind the hidden blue Exceed/cat?

Tags: fairy-tail

In Fairy Tail Episode 144 (Despair Unleashed), approximately 7 minutes and 42 seconds into it, a blue Exceed/cat can be seen hidden between the rocks in the background.

In the image I took below you can see between Happy and Panther Lily the blue Exceed/cat.

[image: hidden character]

This is not addressed this during the episode and the characters in the scene do not mention anything about it.

Is there ever an actual explanation behind this? Or is it some type of Easter egg?

Comment: related, if not a dupe: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/10063/who-is-this-green-guy

Answer (score 1):

It's just an easter egg, they seem to appear in every episode. They're no part of the plot in any way.

Example: [image]

In earlier episodes, they showed a still image of every easter egg animal in the episode with the relevant at the end of the episode.

Source: [fanpop - Fairy Tail Question - In episode 39, what is this thing?](https://www.fanpop.com/clubs/fairy-tail/answers/show/538421/episode-39-what-thing)